# PHP - How to retrieve session in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, session-variables

I created a table that contains `id - names - jobs` and page that shows the names only and beside each name there is button `Job` and session that contains the id. this is my code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array("$query")){
$name = $fetch['names'];
$id = $fetch['id'];
echo '</br>';
echo $name;
$_SESSION['name'] = $id;
echo "<button>Job</button>";
}
```

I want when the user click on button `Job` redirect to a page that contains the job of that session. so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `echo` line with:

```
echo "<button onclick='document.location=\"show_job.php?id=$id\">Job</button>";
```

By the way, storing the $id in $_SESSION won't work - there is only one $_SESSION per web session, and since you are listing different jobs, `$_SESSION['id']` will contain the LAST `$id`.

Comment: @KlausJasper you have only 1! variable, how can you store all ids in it?

Comment: You will need to show some identifier, otherwise there is no way to figure out which button was pressed. You can use a substitute, keeping a mapping of substitute=>actual id in $_SESSION (use `session_start()` at the top of your php file, as Frasci suggested), to keep them, but you still need to indicate which button was pressed. You can hide it further - as soon as they request show_job.php, store the result in $_SESSION, then redirect them to show_job.php without an id; when the page is requested again, retrieve it from $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

you rewrite your $_SESSION variable each loop, so it will contain only tha last id from table

the only way I see, is to make a link `<a href="?job_id=$id>Job</a>` and query exact job on the page like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$_GET['job_id']`

anyway you have to write it somewhere in html, because server-side script need to know what id are you looking

Imo you don't really understand what's happening between client and server sides, but I cannot provide you a link to a tutorial, because it is a long time when I used them last time

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way than using session. Because the way you're using session, only one ID can be saved at once.

Instead of button, try using a link with ID as a param.

```
<a href="link-to-target-page?id=$id">Job</a>
```

And on that target page

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now you have the ID in the target page. If you want to load lot more stuff than just a job, try pulling from DB.

On the other hand if you want to show only a job here, this entire thing is a bad implementation. Cause dont make the user redirect to a new page just to see a job title. Allow him to see it in the first page itself.